# Which is correct: considered vs considerably

Tags: word-usage, exam-questions

The target sentence is from TOEIC and goes:

> The latest version of the TR21 printer is _____ more reliable than previous models.

A. considered
B. considerably

The answer according to the book is 'considered', but I am not totally convinced. In my opinion, the second option 'considerably' is not wrong either. Please share your ideas.

Comment: Either could be used, they just mean different things.

Comment: Both are correct answers; it's the material that's incorrect. Terrible question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used *considered*, the meaning of the sentence would be that that specific printer is commonly recognised to be more reliable than those before.

In the second case, the afterglow you get resembles more a personal evaluation based on experience than a widely known thing.

Still, both sentences are correct. I agree with you. I think the phrase should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This a bad test question, because both choices would create correct and plausible sentences, with different meanings.

> - The latest version of the TR21 printer is considered more reliable than previous models. (*people hold the opinion that the TR21 is more reliable*)
> - The latest version of the TR21 printer is considerably more reliable than previous models. (*The TR21 is much more reliable*)

There is no wrong answer here.